# Select from database where string = same string with diacritics

Tags: mysql

How can I select from database by given string and mysql to return the row on same string with diacritics?

```
select * from myTable where nume = "Stefan"
```

and the row from database that should be returned:

```
id = 1 
name = "Ștefan"
```

Comment: can you give sample output?

Comment: This is dependent on language in which you want to compare strings. Different collations treat diacriticts differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search like:

```
SELECT * from myTable 
where 
CONVERT(nume USING utf8) LIKE '%Stefan%'
```

But this is a bit unclear, as MySql already know how to search for strings with diactritics.